# Converting to xml to json

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using the **xml2json** module to convert a XML payload into JSON, but the i am seeing the following

If i have the following

```
var xml = <Stat />;

var obj = xml2json.toJson(xml, {});
```

The **obj["Stat"]** is being picked up as empty **{}** rather than a empty **""**.

**EDIT**
Lets say we have a nested xml structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ABC>
   <RECORD>
        <STAT />
   </RECORD>
</ABC>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not do that using `xml2json`

Use `xml2js` instead:

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var xml = "<Stat />"
parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    console.dir(result); // { Stat: '' }
});
```

Comment: i see it being picked up as Stat:[ 0: '' ]